# How to remove highlight of a selected row (or cell) in a wpf datagrid using code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have found this piece of code working perfecty in wpf xaml.
How to do this in code behind?

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FF0000"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From code behind you can add resources like this -

```
  dataGrid.Resources.Add(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey, "#FF0000");
```

You need to get the grid object, then in resources of that grid add a new resource